# Program crash on load

Tags: c++

I have no error in compilation, but my program crashes just after it starts.

My source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> recursivite(std::vector<int> source, int index, int length);
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myTab  {{ 1, 2, 3, 4,
                                5, 6, 7, 8,
                                9, 10, 11, 12,
                                13, 14, 15, 16,
                                17, 18, 19, 20
                            }};

    std::vector<int> myTab2{{0, 0, 0, 0}};

    myTab2 = recursivite(myTab, 4, 4);

    for (unsigned int i{}; i < myTab2.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << myTab2[i];
}

std::vector<int> recursivite(std::vector<int> source, int index, int length)
{
    std::vector<int> myTab = {length};

    if (myTab.size() > 0)
    {
        myTab[length - 1] = source[index + length - 1];
        recursivite(source, index, length - 1);
    }

    return myTab;
}
```

Can someone figure out why it is crashing?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a stackoverflow error you see? If so, check what's the end condition of your `recursivite` function. As far as I can see, it's going to be in an infinite recursion. I could be wrong.

Comment: what is `std::vector<int> myTab = {length};` for?  `length` is an int.

Comment: also when would `if (myTab.size() > 0)` not be true if you are adding things to `myTab`

Comment: I think there's a `std::vector(args)` / `std::vector{args}` mixup here.

Comment: `unsigned int i{}` Why? It's just confusing.

Comment: When `length` is 4, you're making a vector with one element (4) and then accessing the fourth element, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that this line probably doesn't do what you want it to do:

```
std::vector<int> myTab = {length};
```

It create a vector with one element. That is, you'll get an infinite recursion as the `myTab.size()` never becomes zero as well as out of bound accesses. You probably meant to use

```
std::vector<int> myTable(length);
```

The version using braces construct the `std::vector<int>` from an `std::initializer_list<int>` listing its elements. The version using parenthesis creates an `std::vector<int>` of the specified size.